# track PID of a background process and store it along with the process name in linux

Tags: linux, shell, centos

i want to save the PID of a background process and save it to a file along with the process name in linux.
What is the command to do so?
Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you call the “process name” but in Bourne shells you get the PID of a background process with the shell variable `$!`. For example:

```
sleep 1000 &
echo "$! sleep 1000" >>/tmp/save_file.txt
```